# Can a hard drive be added to the same volume group of LVM as a SSD?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

My workstation currently consists of an SSD (250 GB) with `/root` (50 GB) and `/home` partitions (184 GB). This is mounted through LVM and the filesystem is xfs. Since I have run out space on my `/root` partition and as xfs cannot be resized I was thinking if I would be able to mount a HDD (4TB) to the same volume group and then increase the size of the partitions.

The doubt I am having is that some sources suggest that disks of different types shouldn't be mixed in the same volume group. If that is the case should I mount the HDD in a new volume group and move my `/home` partition there, while keeping the SSD only for `/root`?

I am using centos 8 and my LVS and drive information is as follows

```
[root@localhost /]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     63G  533M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     63G  107M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                     63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root       50G   50G  338M 100% /
/dev/mapper/cl-home      184G   44G  140G  24% /home
/dev/sda1                976M  208M  701M  23% /boot
tmpfs                     13G   12K   13G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                     13G  724K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/centos-home  3.4T  231G  3.2T   7% /run/media/drive/98b81f55-fdab-4bce-be5b-74c1b89c422b



# LVS

[root@localhost /]# lvs -v
  LV   VG     #Seg Attr       LSize   Maj Min KMaj KMin Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Cpy%Sync Log Convert LV UUID                                LProfile
  home centos    1 -wi-ao----  <3.37t  -1  -1  253    4                                                     EOxWKK-4w7U-wKXf-5eW2-mcLG-bN8y-cT9Vx1         
  root centos    1 -wi-a----- 150.00g  -1  -1  253    3                                                     MYIBHl-qoGa-S824-7qdz-Oncg-XaDk-T1FCmT         
  swap centos    1 -wi-a----- 128.00g  -1  -1  253    5                                                     xfB0iJ-cCAJ-Ic2M-e6iq-VNBZ-3LwV-VNBu4Z         
  home cl        1 -wi-ao---- 183.47g  -1  -1  253    2                                                     g2nm5Y-3Cyw-b67w-oG9s-PXMp-cwfS-i4CO6c         
  root cl        1 -wi-ao----  50.00g  -1  -1  253    0                                                     3OMv3F-YsC3-fGLz-BM3i-TWO1-5vwD-1JvVtn         
  swap cl        1 -wi-ao----   4.00g  -1  -1  253    1                                                     Ggg0v1-rQKZ-dRtw-EL3w-p2wk-O9Ob-90ctTz         


# VGS


[root@localhost /]# vgs -v && pvs -v
  VG     Attr   Ext   #PV #LV #SN VSize   VFree VG UUID                                VProfile
  centos wz--n- 4.00m   1   3   0  <3.64t    0  nla0t6-6hEL-Co6Y-cu5D-q5wK-dPDs-OWCSvQ         
  cl     wz--n- 4.00m   1   3   0 237.47g    0  7VK3M5-O03p-83Nk-FqkH-zWdt-Beck-UxLNBp         

#PVS

  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree DevSize PV UUID                               
  /dev/sda2  cl     lvm2 a--  237.47g    0  237.47g eB7ywS-2XAB-obEK-lO3Z-zMDR-S62y-xhP85m
  /dev/sdb3  centos lvm2 a--   <3.64t    0   <3.64t JpZ2E0-7WdZ-ksHb-71wd-6EP1-fKYU-jHLhbf
```

The SSD has is in vg `cl` and HDD in `centos`, the partitons and volume group are from a past installation of centos and I am aware that i would need to do a reformat and do fresh partitions in-order to mount it in the same volume group `cl`.

Answer (score 0):

> as xfs cannot be resized

I think that is wrong. xfs might not be shrinkable, but it can be grown (I've done that).

> disks of different types shouldn't be mixed in the same volume group

Notice that it (although that is your own words) is a *shouldn't* not a *can't*.
LVM doesn't care about the technology, so you *can* do it. Whether you should is an entirely different matter, there might be good reasons not to, personally I don't know, but I think the sources you have already found will list arguments.

Comment: > I think that is wrong. xfs might not be shrinkable, but it can be grown (I've done that).
Sorry, for not being clear that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion.

You've used hardly any of your `/home`. I'd suggest you copy off the data there to your external disk and remake the `/home` LVM  at around 60GB. Going forwards, increase the root partition (or `/home`) by only around 10GB at a time.

The big problem with mixing SSDs and HDDs in the same volume group is that you are potentially downgrading the VG speed. In your case adding an external drive also builds in a dependency on that drive - you then can't boot without it. If *either* disk dies your system is toast. My suggestion would be to use it for regular backups of your system.

Comment: Thanks @roaima that was one of the fears I had. I think I would back up my `/home` partition and remove it so as to grow the `/root` partiton and the rebuild it with a smaller size. While mounting the HDD in a separate vg as you suggested.  Although I was thinking creating a symbolic link between a folder in  `/home` and the new mount of vg HDD. Would this be a problem?
Thanks again.

Comment: Just mount the new home directory tree on `/home`. Little point mounting it somewhere else and making a symlink